# TableRow adicionado via programa nao esta trazendo todos os campos!

Tags: java, android, table, rolamento

Estou tentando fazer um `ScrollView - TableLayout - TableRow` via programa, porem usando um Layout XML como base dos dados internos das TableRows.

Acontece que sempre que tento adicionar o texto do ultimo campo (mensagem) deste layout ou somente inflo o layout, ele faz sumir algumas definicoes que estao direto no xml e o campo dt_envio deixa de aparecer.

Devo estar fazendo alguma coisa errada, mas nao consigo encontrar o erro!
Alguem poderia me ajudar?

fragment_comunicado.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoEscola"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_escola" />
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame_comunicado"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="290dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp">
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_comunicado_tablerow.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_remetente"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="71dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_chat" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_seta_close" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/remetente"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Remetente Remetente Remetente Remetente Remetente"
                android:textColor="@color/azul_painel"
                android:textSize="7pt"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dt_envio"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="99-99-9999"
                android:textSize="5pt"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/assunto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Assunto Email"
            android:textColor="@color/azul_painel"
            android:textSize="6pt"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mensagem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Inicio Email"
            android:textColor="@color/azul1_painel"
            android:textSize="6pt"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentComunicado.java

```
public class FragmentComunicado extends Fragment{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_comunicado, container, false);
    ((MenuPrincipal)getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Comunicado");

    //** Fazer Chamada pesquisa dos comunicados por: aluno e ano

    FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.content_frame_comunicado);
    fl.removeAllViews();

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(rootView.getContext());
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lpsv = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    sv.setLayoutParams(lpsv);

    TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(rootView.getContext());
    TableLayout.LayoutParams lptl = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    tl.setLayoutParams(lptl);
    sv.addView(tl);

    for (int i = 1; i <10; i++){
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(rootView.getContext());
        tl.addView(tr);

        View tablerow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_comunicado_tablerow, tr, false);

        ImageView img_remetente = (ImageView) tablerow.findViewById(R.id.img_remetente);
        img_remetente.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_escola);

        TextView remetente = (TextView) tablerow.findViewById(R.id.remetente);
        remetente.setText("Coord. Educacao Infantil");

        TextView dt_envio = (TextView) tablerow.findViewById(R.id.dt_envio);
        dt_envio.setText("02/01/2016");

        TextView assunto = (TextView) tablerow.findViewById(R.id.assunto);
        assunto.setText("Inicio Curso de Ferias");

        TextView mensagem = (TextView) tablerow.findViewById(R.id.mensagem);
        mensagem.setText("Bom dia Srs Pais, Nosso curso de ferias inicia-se cheio de atividades para nossos pequenos!!! Nesta semana teremos aventura no zoologico");

        tr.addView(tablerow);


    }

    fl.addView(sv);

    return rootView;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oie pessoal,

Era questao de "tirar as orelhas dos olhos" mesmo.

Quando montei minha TableRow via programa, esqueci de montar o layout_height e o layout_width. Assim que montei, funcionou perfeitamente. :D